# Change ListView font

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

Is there any way that I can speed up the changing of fonts in my app?

I have a `ListView` that loads its list from an XML online. It's all good, but I need to change its font to a custom font from my assets folder.

When i applied:

```
 TxEventName = (TextView)row.findViewById(id.eventNameTx);
 TxEventName.setText(getEventsCount(position));
 TxEventName.setTypeface(Utilities.textFont(this.getContext()));
```

it becomes slow, since I applied the `setTypeface`.

Sometimes it would load the UI layout first then the list, sometimes it would just be a delaying black screen then, when the next activity comes out, the list is already there.

I am even using `AsyncTask` to load the values for the list which is something like:

```
private class initList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        SimpleDateFormat formatterc; 
        Date xdatec=null; 
        formatterc = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
        try {
            xdatec = (Date)formatterc.parse(date);
            SimpleDateFormat frmtr = new SimpleDateFormat(dateTemplateForChecking);
            selectedDate = frmtr.format(xdatec).toString();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < XMLParser.ppEvents.size(); i++) {
            EventsObj evObj = XMLParser.ppEvents.get(i);

            for(int j = 0; j < evObj.date.size(); j++) {
                if(selectedDate.equalsIgnoreCase(evObj.date.get(j))) {

                    StringBuilder sbldr = new StringBuilder();
                    sbldr.append(evObj.act_id);
                    sbldr.append("!");
                    if (SelectLanguage.lang == "ENG"){
                    sbldr.append(evObj.name_en);
                    } else if (SelectLanguage.lang == "TCH"){
                        sbldr.append(evObj.name_tc);
                    } else if (SelectLanguage.lang == "SCH"){
                        sbldr.append(evObj.name_sc);
                    }

                    mainEvents.add(sbldr.toString());
                    eventID.add(Integer.toString(evObj.act_id));
                }   
            }
        }
        adapter = new events_adapter(PublicProg.this, layout.events_adapter, id.eventNameTx, mainEvents);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        eventList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        Bundle ext = getIntent().getExtras();

        position = ext.getString("position");
        date = ext.getString("date");

        mainEvents = new ArrayList<String>();
        eventID = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this to create simple cache for `Typeface`

```
public class Typefaces{

private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

    public static Typeface get(Context c, String name){
        synchronized(cache){
            if(!cache.containsKey(name)){
                Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                        c.getAssets(), 
                        String.format("fonts/%s.OTF", name)
                    );
                cache.put(name, t);
            }
            return cache.get(name);
        }
    }

}
```

In adapter constructor init your custom `Typeface`

```
myriadBold = Typefaces.get(mContext, "MYRIADPRO-BOLD");
```

and use it in `getView`

```
txt.setTypeface(myriadBold);
```

This way decrease the number system call `skia` to generate custome font.

Comment: wow. thanks. this one took my activities that takes 10 secs to load to only a slight delay of 1 sec.

Comment: can i put this on my splash screen to cache the font in my app?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe where you set the Typeface is not good place.

Also Utilities.textFont(this.getContext()), with this you are probably reading the font from the filesystem, which can slow your process and depending on where this line is called, you are locking the UI.

Answer (score 0):

you can set `Typeface` through your custom `TextView`

```
public class TextViewGeorgiaBold extends TextView {

Resources res = getResources();
String font_path = res.getString(R.string.MAIN_FONT);

public TextViewGeorgiaBold(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context.getApplicationContext(), attrs, defStyle);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext()
            .getApplicationContext().getAssets(), font_path);
    setTypeface(font);
}

public TextViewGeorgiaBold(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context.getApplicationContext(), attrs);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext()
            .getApplicationContext().getAssets(), font_path);
    setTypeface(font);

}

public TextViewGeorgiaBold(Context context) {
    super(context.getApplicationContext());
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext()
            .getApplicationContext().getAssets(), font_path);
    setTypeface(font);
}

}
```

as It sets the `TypeFace` at the time of inflation of layout.

may be it will help you.